# How to use current user as related field in Drupal 7 Views?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

When users register they associate to one or more locations via user profile. Location is a custom content type. I have a custom field in the user profile defining a relation to this location.

I have a user-type view that returns un-authenticated users and is restricted to elevated role users. I'd like to add a filter that only returns un-authenticated users whose associated location value(s) match one or more location values from the current user requesting the view.

I can filter by the associated location, but I can't relate that value to the current user's value(s). I feel like I might be able to do this if I could add the current user uid to the relationships area and not just the contextual filters area. Can I do this without resorting to a custom filter or relationship?

**EDIT:**

There may be some confusion so maybe this will help clarify.

`User -> Profile -> Location` is the data association chain. I want to only show users whose Location value(s) match those of the currently logged-in user.

`User (any) -> Profile (Student) -> Location(s) == User (current) -> Profile (admin) -> Location(s)`

I could write SQL to do this but it's not clear if this is possible to do using views alone, or if I need a custom relationship or filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this within views is the following:

1. Make View of using User type
2. add a Relationship to a [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) type (in my case 'Student')
3. Add Contextual Filter of type profile:student:location
4. select "provide default value"
5. type: "php code"
6. Use the following code:

   ```
   global $user;
   $profile = profile2_load_by_user($user->uid,'facilitator');
   if (!$profile) { return ''; }
   if (!isset($profile->field_location['und'])) { return ''; }
   $locations='';
   foreach ($profile->field_location['und'] as $location) {
     $locations.=','.$location['nid'];
   }
   return substr($locations,1);
   ```
7. Under "More", Set "Allow Multiple Values" to TRUE
8. Save your Contextual Filter

Using PHP in this manner, you can load the current User and get associated values to filter by. This may be useful in many other contexts and circumstances.